# how use regex to get from specific point to end of text?

Tags: regex

I want to know what is the proper regular expression for that :

```
In an action unprecedented during 12 years of war in Afghanistan, the commandant of the Marine Corps is firing two top generals. See why: 

<a onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLin.swap()>Generals fired over Taliban attack </a><br/>security.blogs.cnn.com<br/>There were three investigations of the incident.
```

I want to do the following :

give me string starting of a tag which contains onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLin.swap() in any position at properties area .. and end with the end of the remain string .. i mean from this a tag to end of the string

**MY TRY :-**

i used this pattern :

```
<a[^>]*?onmouseover\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]*?)['\"][^>]*?/?>
```

it got successfully this part `<a onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLin.swap()>`
i want to get also all remain tags and text to the end point

Note :

My friends, I know that using regex with html tag is very bad practice and i already have red that alot but i want that for special case

thank in advance :)

Comment: You should also put what your exact expected match should look like.  Describing it in words can be ambiguous.

Comment: ok pal .. i want to return all of that from the top text ( <a onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLin.swap()>Generals fired over Taliban attack </a><br/>security.blogs.cnn.com<br/>There were three investigations of the incident. )

Comment: so @Derek answer does this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
onmouseover.*
```